# Extends vs including a typeclass argument

Tags: lean, lean-mathlib, lean3, type-class

In the Lean mathlib, I see some places where a typeclass argument is included in a class definition, such as [`locally_finite_order`](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/ca2450fe5decefce4bee05e727622e32f2c985ad/src/order/locally_finite.lean#L108). In other places, I see the "`extends`" keyword used, such as [`ring`](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/ca2450fe5decefce4bee05e727622e32f2c985ad/src/algebra/ring/basic.lean#L666). What are the differences and tradeoffs between these two ways of doing things?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Section 2.2 of Anne Baanen's recent paper [Use and abuse of instance parameters in the Lean mathematical library](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.01629.pdf) gives a very nice explanation of this, referring to them as "unbundled subclasses" (like `locally_finite_order`) and "bundled subclasses" (like `ring`). This paper discusses, in various places, situations where we might prefer one over the other.

One example is in section 5.1. Defining a class

```
class module (R M : Type) extends add_comm_monoid M := ...
```

would automatically create an instance that says, "in order to show `add_comm_monoid T`, it suffices to show `module ?x T`." Instances like this can lead to huge performance issues, so the preferred pattern here is the unbundled definition:

```
class module (R M : Type) [add_comm_monoid M] := ...
```

In the other direction, overuse of unbundled subclasses can lead to performance problems of a different kind (Baanen section 10, or a [blog post by Ralf Jung](https://www.ralfj.de/blog/2019/05/15/typeclasses-exponential-blowup.html)). Full unbundling leads to exponential blowup in the number of type class arguments (and thus searches) needed as you climb a hierarchy of classes. Baanen gives the example:

```
instance prod.comm_monoid
  [has_one M] [has_one N] [has_mul M] [has_mul N]
  [semigroup M] [semigroup N] [mul_one_class M] [mul_one_class N]
  [monoid M] [monoid N] [comm_semigroup M] [comm_semigroup N]
  [comm_monoid M] [comm_monoid N] :
comm_monoid (M × N) := ...
```